# How to reference stylesheet from subfolder express and ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am having a problem referencing a stylesheet from a subfolder in views.
Here is my folder structure:

```js
-Nattcup_git
  -index.js
  -views
    -control.ejs
    -index.ejs
    -brukere.ejs
    -404.ejs
    -oppsett
      -index.ejs
      -cup.ejs
    -partials
      -head.ejs
  -public
    -style.css
```

Here is the (important) code in the app (index.js):

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config()
}
const path = require('path');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const express = require("express");
const oppsettRoute = require('./routes/oppsett');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const {JsonDB} = require("node-json-db");
const {Config} = require("node-json-db/dist/lib/JsonDBConfig")
const flash = require('express-flash')
const session = require('express-session')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

let db = new JsonDB(new Config("db",true,false,'/'));
let tilgangDB = new JsonDB(new Config('tilgangsnivåer.json', true, false, '/'))

const passport = require('passport')

const initializePassport = require('./passport-config')
initializePassport(
    passport,
    brukernavn => db.getData('/brukere').find(user => user.brukernavn === brukernavn),
    id => db.getData('/brukere').find(user => user.id === id)
)


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Listening at " + PORT));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {tittel: "Hjem", tilgang: typeTilgang(req), brukernavn: brukernavn(req)});
})

app.get('/index', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {tittel: "Hjem", tilgang: typeTilgang(req), brukernavn: brukernavn(req)});
})

app.get('/tabell', (req, res) => {
    res.render('tabell', {tittel: "Tabell", tilgang: typeTilgang(req), brukernavn: brukernavn(req), kamper: db.getData('/cuper/Nattcup2022/kamper')})
})

app.get('/control', harTilgang, (req, res) => {
    res.render('control', {tittel: "Kontrollpanel", tilgang: typeTilgang(req), brukernavn: req.user.brukernavn, status: db.getData('/cuper/Nattcup2022/status')});
})

app.get('/live', (req, res) => {
    res.render('live', {tittel: "Live"})
})

app.get('/login', notAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('login', {tittel: "Logg inn", tilgang: typeTilgang(req)})
})

app.get('/registrer', harTilgang, (req, res) => {
    res.render('registrer', {tittel: "Registrer bruker", tilgang: typeTilgang(req), brukernavn: brukernavn(req), roller: tilgangDB.getData('/roller')})
})

app.get('/brukere', harTilgang, (req, res) => {
    res.render('brukere', {tittel: "Brukere", tilgang: typeTilgang(req), brukernavn: brukernavn(req), brukere: hentBrukere()})
})

app.use('/oppsett', oppsettRoute);

app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
    try {
        let path = req.header("path");
        let data = db.getData("/cuper/Nattcup2022/" + path);
        res.json(data);
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})


app.post("/data/endre", forwardAuthenticated, (request, response) => {
     if (request.body.type === "mal"){
        let lag = request.body["lag"];
        let operator = request.body["operator"];
        let kampid = request.body["kampid"];
        let path = `/cuper/Nattcup2022/mal/${kampid}/mal${lag}`
        db.push(path, db.getData(path) + Number(operator + 1));
        oppdaterStatus();

    } else if (request.body.type === "endre"){
        let nr = db.getData("/cuper/Nattcup2022/status/livekamp/kampnr") + request.body.nr;
        oppdaterStatus(nr);
    } else if(request.body.type === "innstilling"){
        db.push('/cuper/Nattcup2022/status/innstillinger/' + request.body["innstilling"], request.body["status"]);
    }
})

app.post('/registrer', harTilgang, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let brukernavn = req.body.brukernavn;
        let passord = req.body.passord;
        if(brukernavn === ""){
            req.flash('error', 'Brukernavn kan ikke være tomt');
            res.redirect('/registrer');
        }
        else if(db.getData('/brukere').find(bruker => bruker.brukernavn === brukernavn)) {
            req.flash("error", "Brukernavnet er allerede i bruk");
            res.redirect('/registrer');
        }
        else if(passord === ""){
            req.flash('error', 'Passordfeltet kan ikke være tomt');
            res.redirect('/registrer');
        }
        else if(passord.length < 8){
            req.flash('error', 'Passord må være minst 8 tegn langt');
            res.redirect('/registrer');
        }
        else {
            const hash = await bcrypt.hash(passord, 10)
            db.push('/brukere[]', {
                id: Date.now().toString(),
                brukernavn: req.body.brukernavn,
                passord: hash,
                tilgang: req.body.rolle
            })
            res.redirect('/brukere');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        req.flash('error', "Noe gikk galt ved registrering. /n Vennligst prøv på nytt /n(" + e + ")")
        res.redirect('/registrer')

    }
})

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}))

app.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut();
    res.redirect('/');
})

app.delete('/slett_bruker', harTilgang, (req, res) => {
    let brukere = db.getData('/brukere')
    let id = req.body.id;
    if(brukere.find(bruker => bruker.id === id)){
        let bruker = brukere.find(bruker => bruker.id === id);
        let index = brukere.indexOf(bruker)
        db.delete('/brukere[' + index + ']')
    }
})


app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).render('404', {tittel: "404", tilgang: typeTilgang(req), brukernavn: brukernavn(req)})
})
```

Then in cup.ejs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="no">
<%- include('../partials/head')%>
<body>
<%- include('../partials/meny')%>

<%- include('../partials/footer')%>
</body>
</html>
```

The file head.ejs that i am including above looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Cup | <%= tittel %></title>
</head>
```

Why won't style.css be applied to cup.ejs?

Thanks

.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: From what URL does the browser try to load the stylesheet? What does the network trace say?

Comment: The browser tries to load it from localhost:5000/oppsett/cuper/style.css i believe

Comment: But on your server, `style.css` is not below `oppset`, and `cuper` does not appear at all in your folder structure.

Comment: yeah, but that is because the get path for the file is localhost:5000/cuper, but that renders  cup.ejs

Comment: Then you must probably write `app.use("/cuper", express.static("public"));`. To be sure, we need more from your `index.js`, the important parts are still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Either `index.js` must contain

```js
app.use("/oppsett/cuper", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

or, better, `routes/oppsett/index.js` (the file that contains the `oppsettRoute`, which you have not given) must contain

```js
app.use("/cuper", express.static("relative path from /routes to /public"));
```

The latter is better because the stylesheet belongs to the `cup.ejs` HTML page, and that also comes from the `oppsettRoute`.

Comment: Would this work as router.use('cuper', express.static("../../public")

Comment: Depends on where your `router` directory sits.

Comment: In routes/oppsett/index.js I declare a router, and then use that to hande the requests to the '/oppsett' route. That router is the export for this file, and is imported as ```oppsettRoute``` How can i serve static pages from here, so that it doesnt have to crowd up my main file (index.js/the app)?

Comment: routes/oppsett/index.js:```const express = require('express');
const tilgang = require('../../tilgangsbehandling.js');
const oppsettController = require('../../controllers/oppsettController');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/' , tilgang.harTilgang, oppsettController.oppsett_index);

router.get('/cuper/:navn', tilgang.harTilgang, oppsettController.oppsett_cup);

module.exports = router;```

Comment: I found that it works if I do ```router.use('/cuper', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')))```